# Android - Build application for SDK 5?

Tags: sdk, android

I'm trying use an object which wasn't available until SDK level 5. It seems the only options are API 1.6 which uses SDK 4 and the next available option is using 2.1 which uses SDK 7.

If I try setting the target to 1.6 and setting minSdkVersion to 5 it obviously errors.

Is the only way around this to jump straight to 2.1?

Comment: Did you try to set both the target and min SdkVersion to 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `targetSdkVersion` to 7 (Android 2.1) and your `minSdkVersion` to 4 (Android 1.6).

Remember that using targeting SDK methods on Android devices that has a lower Android version than your target SDK will result in a crash. It's important to remember because you might wanna check which version the user's phone has at runtime and select a different route if the target API isn't supported.

Comment: Thanks, however there doesn't seem to be an android 2.0 sdk option available within the AVD manager. Do you have any suggestion as to why? Or, even better, do you know how to/where to find out how to set an image as a wallpaper pre SDK 5? I've tried searching but all that comes up is to use the WallpaperManager

Comment: @jblz: I don't think that the 2.0 SDK is left in the package which we gets from Google since 2.0 was only existing a few weeks/months, although, I can be wrong here. So you will end up with setting your target to 7 (Android 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use SDK 7, as SDK 5 is obsolete.

However, let's say that you were editing the Android Manifest, and needed a tag or attribute only available at a higher SDK, like `android:installLocation`. In this case, you would change the Eclipse build settings to the higher number and leave `minSdkVersion` the way it is. All phones below the build version number would ignore the tag.